# How to find the Line number that starts with specific character from a text file in VB.NET?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, etl, flat-file

There is a text file that having records more than 10,000 lines.

Each line starts with a specific number like 1,2,3,4 and 5. Each number indicates whether it's a header, main data, file detail, footer etc.

So, we need to find out the line number that starts with specific character, so that I can assign that value to read the text line for specific things.

Comment: Is it vb.net or vbscript? To make the question more clear, please edit and add a sample input text and expected output values.

Comment: @Vignesh are you working with SSIS or vb.net app?? your question is not clear

Answer (score 2):

### SSIS Solution

Add a variable that increment by 1 on each line and check the first character using `Substring` function.

Assuming that the first column name is `Column0`

You can add a script component in the DataFlow Task and use a similar code: (using Vb.Net)

```
Dim intR As Integer = 0

Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)


    intR += 1

    If Not Row.Column0_IsNull AndAlso
           Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.Column0.Trim) Then

        Select Case Row.Column0.Substring(0, 1)


            Case "1"

                'Line number is stored in intR

            Case "2"

                ...

           Case Else


        End Select

    End If




End Sub
```

### Simple Vb app Solution

*If working with an vb.net application, you can use StreamReader to read the textfile line by line*

```
Using sr as new Io.StreamReader("C:\File1.txt")

    Dim intR as Integer = 0

    While Not sr.EndOfStream

        intR += 1

        dim strLine as string = sr.ReadLine()

        Select Case strLine.Substring(0,1)

            Case "1"
               'Line number is stored in intR

            Case "2"

            ...


        End Select

    End While


End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a need for manipulation i would save all data inside a data structure (in my example `HashSet`).
 each Line as `Line` object (`Structure Line`) with 2 fields, `OperationNumberNumber` and `LineText`. 
 now that everything is arranged inside the hashset you can manipulate, sort, use Linq or Lambda expressions etc.. in an efficient manner.

```
Private fileData As New HashSet(Of Line)

Private Sub Foo()
    Dim TextLine As String = String.Empty
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FilePath)

    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        ' read line '
        TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
        If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextLine)) Then
        ' create line object '
        Dim line = New Line()
        ' extract the line number '
        line.OperationNumberNumber = TextLine.Substring(0, 1)
        ' extract the line text '
        line.LineText = TextLine.Substring(1, TextLine.Length - 1)
        ' save to hashset '
        fileData.Add(line)
        End If
    Loop

End Sub

Structure Line
    Public OperationNumberNumber As Integer
    Public LineText As String
End Structure
```